# Can undeleting/deleting answers allow users to unfairly acquire badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

If you delete an answer you lose all of your reputation points you gained on it, but after you undelete it you gain it all back.

What stops someone from abusing this mechanic to get epic/legendary badges? So lets say every other day I delete five answers that are worth 200 points, and the days between those days I undelete them.

That would make my rep per day look like this:

-200 +200 -200 +200, etc.

Technically every other day would count for epic/legendary.
 
Is there anything in place stopping this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The days when you earned 200+ reputation don't count towards the Epic and Legendary badges if you delete the posts that earned you the points.

The counter will tick over when you reach 200, but if you subsequently lose the points the count is reduced.

You can't game the system this way.

Comment: Most noteably, undeleting posts doesn't cause a new +200 to appear in your reputation history anyways. It just removes the -200 like the posts were never deleted in the first place. So all those days would *not* look like -200 +200 -200 +200, they'd just look like days where nothing happened.

Comment: and what about the disciplined badge ? can we delete a +3 post to earn it and then undelete ?

Comment: I recently saw a badge was awarded for a First Time Rollback. This person defaced his question and somebody corrected it. Then the OP *rolled it back* – the exact requirement to gain a badge – to its defaced state. (Fortunately it did not go by unnoticed and that user is now temporarily banned.)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `:P` re-posted without the link. Then again, that particular user rolled back the rollbacks about 8 times and tried "edit" to **destroy the answer** as well – *twice*. I really don't emphasize that much with him.

Comment: Banned for 1 month. What do you have to do to get banned for 1 _year_ ? post an answer containing a video where you kill a unicorn while disguised as Rick Astley?

Comment: i don't know how you guys handle all these cases.. life is weird, i recently gained a tumbleweed badge after a guy serial-downvoted all my posts so that one got the conditions for it.. his votes were cancelled, but i still have my badge

Comment: the answer is: it doesn't matter. Badges don't give enough power (except for gold tag badges), those are corner cases, not worth trying to "fix"

Comment: I've received Critic badges on some of the sites that I'm registered on after accidentally down-voting something and then immediately reversing the down votes. What surprised me was that I still had the badges even though I had immediately reversed the accidental down votes.

Comment: @RobH it's a general principle on SO that you don't lose badges even if the conditions for gaining it are removed.  This is why you keep your Populist badge even if the accepted answerer catches up with you.

Comment: @Kaddath that is how I got the [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious?userid=4298200) badge recently! Apparently I had a lot of score 1 accepted answers..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Imagine this, but repeatedly, with some Be Nice violation thrown in. After at least one prior suspension. That's a single case of one-year suspension material, so your mileage may vary. (Of course, if a user is _really_ bad, they can get suspended for a year or more straight out... but you do _not_ want to know why.)

Comment: @LonelyNeuron same thing for unsung hero then: downvotes make a lot of 0-accepted answers => gold unsung :) note that tag badges can be lost

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes IIRC You can delete an answer to get the Disciplined badge and then undelete the answer to retain the badge and the answer. The argument there is most badges you have earned are not revoked if you lose the requirements to have the badge, because you *did* earn it at one point. The exception I think is tag badges, since those can confer extra privileges, you need to maintain the requirements for them.

Comment: exactly. Badges you're keeping because of those cornercase have little to no power.

Comment: @usr2564301 Obviously once you get into a 8-time rollback fight with the mods, it's safe to say that you've gone a bit overboard, but just to play devil's advocate, I'm going to ask: If he posted the question in the first place, why is it wrong for him to want to delete his own question? Isn't deleting content that the creator changed their mind about a fairly common occurrence on this site?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, once a question is answered (with a reasonable answer), trying to get rid of the question is prohibited. If the answer is up-voted, the system will prevent the question from being deleted by the poster. Users sometimes try to post a question (about their homework), wait for an answer to come in, and then get rid of the question so their teacher doesn't find it.

Comment: @dfeuer If this only kicks in with upvoted answers, how can this prevent homework abuse? All the OP has to do is watch the page and, as soon as somebody posts an answer, delete the question before anyone has a chance to upvote it.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, if they do that, then someone will usually undelete the question promptly. If they delete it again, moderators will step in and they won't like it very much. That's been my experience, anyway.

Comment: @animuson care to add your comment to the answer? Because that's what made me actually understand it in the first place.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm going to record a video of myself doing that and find a way to work it into a legitimate answer. Just to test it.

Comment: :) Ping me so I can downvote.